# multiple textfields onChange function issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, onchange

There's a plus button to increase the number of textfields in the page. After increasing the textfields, I want to show all the textfield input value at once under, after clicking on the submit button.
But here it's giving a problem on the onChange setState issue. How to handle it ? Any help ?

Here's the => **[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-upqstr)**

```
class App extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      arr: [],
      firstname: '',
      lastname: '',
      setarr: [],
      temp: []
    };
    this.addTextfields = this.addTextfields.bind(this);
    this.changeFirstname = this.changeFirstname.bind(this);
    this.changeLastname = this.changeLastname.bind(this);
  }

  addTextfields(e) {
    let htmlContent = [];
    htmlContent.push(
      <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="first name" onChange={this.changeFirstname} value={this.state.firstname} /> <br/> <br/>
        <input type="text" placeholder="last name" onChange={this.changeLastname} value={this.state.lastname} /> <br/> <br/>
      </div>
    );
    this.setState({ arr: this.state.arr.concat(htmlContent) });
  }

  changeFirstname(e) {
    this.setState({ firstname: e.target.value });
  }

  changeLastname(e) {
    this.setState({ lastname: e.target.value });
  }

  showTexts() {
    console.log(this.state.firstname, this.state.lastname);
    var add = [this.state.firstname, this.state.lastname];
    this.state.temp = this.state.temp.concat(add);
    this.setState({ setarr: this.state.temp, firstname: '', lastname: '' });
    // localStorage.setItem(this.state.arr, 'names');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="App">
          <input type="text" onChange={this.changeFirstname} placeholder="first name" value={this.state.firstname} /> <br/> <br/>
          <input type="text" onChange={this.changeLastname} placeholder="last name" value={this.state.lastname} /> <br/> <br/>
          <button type="submit" onClick={this.addTextfields}>Plus</button>
          {this.state.arr}
        </div>
        <div className="submit-button">
          <button type="submit" onClick={this.showTexts.bind(this)}>Submit</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          {this.state.setarr}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more on what you want to achieve? I see there can be multiple inputs, but they all are supposed to change same strings (firstname, lastname) in the state and that's a bit confusing.

Comment: By clicking on the plus button increase the input fields and then I just want to type things on the input fields and show all those under the submit button, after clicking on the submit button.

Comment: @Subhojit is it one field or multiple fields and do you want to receive names in them also or can be some random text? also, let us know how your planning to receive the data in those fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think, you are doing it the wrong way. I have created the below sample for reference. Please have a look.

```js
const Form = (props) => {
  return(
    <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="first name" onChange={props.changeFirstname} value={props.firstname} /> <br/> <br/>
        <input type="text" placeholder="last name" onChange={props.changeLastname} value={props.lastname} /> <br/> <br/>
    </div>
  )
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      arr: [
        {
          firstname: '',
          lastname: '',
          id:1
        }
      ],
      showOutput:false
    };
    this.addTextfields = this.addTextfields.bind(this);
    this.changeFirstName = this.changeFirstName.bind(this);
    this.changeLastName = this.changeLastName.bind(this);
  }

  addTextfields(e) {
    debugger
    let oldArray = this.state.arr;
    this.setState((prevState) => { 
      return {
        arr: oldArray.concat({
          firstname: '',
          lastname: '',
          id: prevState.arr.length + 2
        })
      }
    });
  }

  changeFirstName(e, selectedIndex) {
    let updatedArray =  this.state.arr.map((data) => {
      if(data.id === selectedIndex) {
        return Object.assign({}, data, {
          firstname: e.target.value
        })
      } else {
        return data
      }
    })

    this.setState({ arr: updatedArray });
    
  }

  changeLastName(e, selectedIndex) {
    let updatedArray =  this.state.arr.map((data) => {
      if(data.id === selectedIndex) {
        return Object.assign({}, data, {
          lastname: e.target.value
        })
      } else {
        return data
      }
    })
    this.setState({ arr: updatedArray });
  }

  showTexts() {
    this.setState({
      showOutput: true
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="App">
          {
            this.state.arr.map((data, index) => {
              return <Form key={index} data={data} 
                      changeFirstname={(e) => this.changeFirstName(e, data.id)}
                      changeLastname={(e) => this.changeLastName(e, data.id)}
                    />
            })
          }
          <button type="submit" onClick={this.addTextfields}>Plus</button> 
        </div>
        <div className="submit-button">
          <button type="submit" onClick={this.showTexts.bind(this)}>Submit</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          {
            this.state.showOutput && 
            this.state.arr.map((data, index) => {
              return <div>
              {data.firstname}  {data.lastname}
              </div>
            })
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      arr: [
        {
          firstname: "",
          lastname: ""
        }
      ],
      displayValues: []
    };
    this.addTextfields = this.addTextfields.bind(this);
    this.changeFirstname = this.changeFirstname.bind(this);
    this.changeLastname = this.changeLastname.bind(this);
  }

  addTextfields(e) {
    let arr = this.state.arr;
    arr.push({
      firstname: "",
      lastname: ""
    });
    this.setState({ arr });
  }

  changeFirstname(e, index) {
    let arr = this.state.arr;
    arr[index].firstname = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ arr });
  }

  changeLastname(e, index) {
    let arr = this.state.arr;
    arr[index].lastname = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ arr });
  }

  showTexts() {
    let displayValues = [];
    this.state.arr.map(element => {
      console.log(element.firstname, element.lastname);
      var add = element.firstname + " " + element.lastname;
      displayValues.push(add);
    });
    this.setState({ displayValues });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="App">
          {this.state.arr.map((element, index) => {
            return (
              <div key={index}>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  onChange={e => this.changeFirstname(e, index)}
                  placeholder="first name"
                  value={this.state.firstname}
                />{" "}
                <br /> <br />
                <input
                  type="text"
                  onChange={e => this.changeLastname(e, index)}
                  placeholder="last name"
                  value={this.state.lastname}
                />{" "}
                <br /> <br />
              </div>
            );
          })}
          <button type="submit" onClick={this.addTextfields}>
            Plus
          </button>
        </div>
        <div className="submit-button">
          <button type="submit" onClick={this.showTexts.bind(this)}>
            Submit
          </button>
        </div>
        <div>
          {this.state.displayValues.map(element => {
            return <p>{element}</p>;
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

[image: Edit zwln33q3vx]